# LaravelでS3のドライバを使ってGoogle Cloud Storageに接続できない

Tags: php, aws, laravel, google-cloud-storage

[Google cloud storage & Laravel 5](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/44er6g/google_cloud_storage_laravel_5/)

上記の記事を参考にLaravelのFileSystemでAWSのS3のドライバを使ってGoogle Cloud Storageにファイルをアップロードしようとしているのですがうまくいきません。
まずconfig/filesystems.phpのdisksに以下の要素を追加しました。

```
'gcp' => [
         'driver' => 's3',
         'key' => env('GCP_KEY'),
         'secret' => env('GCP_SECRET'),
         'region' => env('GCP_DEFAULT_REGION'),
         'bucket' => env('GCP_BUCKET'),
         'base_url'=> env('GCP_BASE_URL'),
    ],
```

keyとsecretはGoogle Cloud PlatformコンソールのStorage -> 設定 -> 相互運用性 -> 新しいキーを作成 で取得したアクセスキーとシークレットを設定しました。
regionは東京であるap-northeast-1を指定し、bucketもGoogle Cloud Platformで作成したバケットの名前を指定しています。
そしてbase_urlにはhttps://storage.googleapis.comを指定しました。

あと上記のリンク先の記事によるとサービスプロバイダを設定していたので、そのまま同じファイルを作成して、config/app.phpのprovidersに

```
App\Providers\GoogleCloudStorageServiceProvider::class
```

と追加しました。

そして実際に画像を送信するコードを以下のように書きました。

```
$disk = Storage::disk('gcp');
$disk->put('test/test.jpg', $request->image);
```

その後php artisan serveでサーバーを再起動し、ブラウザから画像のアップロードを実行してみたのですが、以下のようなエラーが表示されました。

Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/myproject.appspot.com/test/test.jpg/UnBh154txrnrZFhTv0vI46NmlGlnpYolK8m412VO.jpeg"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/myproject.appspot.com/test/test.jpg/UnBh154txrnrZFhTv0vI46NmlGlnpYolK8m412VO.jpeg` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:  `InvalidAccessKeyId`The AWS Access Key Id you provided (truncated...) InvalidAccessKeyId (client): The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. -  `InvalidAccessKeyId`The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

これはGoogle Cloud PlatformとAWSが連携できていないということでしょうか？
以上の手順で何か抜けているところ、間違っているところはあるでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 手元で動作確認できていないのであれですが `base_url` ではなくて `endpoint` ではないですか？前者はv2、v3では後者？

Comment: endpointに変更したらできました！！ずっと試行錯誤していたので嬉しいです！僕の書いていたのはバージョンが違っていたということでしょうか？

Comment: 上記設定(base_url)を書くのに参考にしたものとかありますか？

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/44er6g/google_cloud_storage_laravel_5/
この辺を参考にしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS SDK for PHP v3においてAPIのエンドポイントは`endpoint`で指定するようです。([当該コード](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/AwsClient.php#L161))

これ自体はv2から変わったことではないようですがGuzzle辺りが当時はS3Clientに渡した`base_url`を使えていたようなのでそういった情報が残っている、のかもしれません。

とりあえずこの質問については

```
         'base_url'=> env('GCP_BASE_URL'),
```

の`base_url` を `endpoint` に変えることでGCPのエンドポイントが使えるようです。

Comment: なるほど、新しく変わっていたのですね。やりたいことができ、とても嬉しいです。ありがとうございました！